# Array Comparision with a string PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

My array result is

```
  Array ( [list] => Bhubaneswar,Cuttack,Angul,Sambalapur )
```

I want to compare this PHP array where at the list is congaing "Bhubaneswar' or not ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Any code / samples of this?

Comment: did you try any php array function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$your_array = array(
    "list" => 'Bhubaneswar,Cuttack,Angul,Sambalapur',
    );
$mystring = $your_array['list'];
$findme   = 'Bhubaneswar';
if(strpos($mystring, $findme) !== false){
    echo "found";
}
```

OR

```
$search = preg_quote('Bhubaneswar', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$your_array = array(
    "list" => 'Bhubaneswar,Cuttack,Angul,Sambalapur',
    );
$result = preg_filter('~' . $search . '~', null, $your_array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_keys($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this one:

```
in_array()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php